# What is the history of the Milky Way's relationship with Andromeda?

Tags: galaxy

From what I've read, the Milky Way will collide with Andromeda in about 4 - 5 billion years, and a billion or so years after that the two will merge and become a giant elliptical galaxy.

What I'm wondering is what the history, orbital dynamics wise, of these two galaxies is? What's set them on the collision course that they now find themselves on? How has the distance between the two varied over time? Could past mergers have robbed one of the two or both of the angular momentum necessary to keep them from colliding?